# Data Frames in R - NA values

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to remove all the rows from my data frame in which the 3rd column is NA:

```
new.frame <- data[(!is.na(data$z)),]
```

But I'm getting an error.

```
Warning message:
In is.na(data$z) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: It sounds like your data frame doesn't have a column called "z".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reproducible examples, please. Here is one that works:

```
R> set.seed(42)
R> DF <- data.frame(a=rnorm(10), b=sample(LETTERS, 10, replace=TRUE), 
+>                  z=cumsum(runif(10)))
R> DF[c(2,4,6),"z"] = NA
R> DF
            a b        z
1   1.3709584 X 0.737596
2  -0.5646982 D       NA
3   0.3631284 Z 1.936759
4   0.6328626 Y       NA
5   0.4042683 C 2.625877
6  -0.1061245 N       NA
7   1.5115220 K 3.466127
8  -0.0946590 X 3.673786
9   2.0184237 L 4.580388
10 -0.0627141 V 5.192166
R> new.frame <- DF[(!is.na(DF$z)),]
R> new.frame
            a b        z
1   1.3709584 X 0.737596
3   0.3631284 Z 1.936759
5   0.4042683 C 2.625877
7   1.5115220 K 3.466127
8  -0.0946590 X 3.673786
9   2.0184237 L 4.580388
10 -0.0627141 V 5.192166
R>
```

Answer (score 3):

There's also `complete.cases()` which may be easier to read. Using Dirk's data:

```
new.frame2 <- DF[complete.cases(DF) ,]

> all.equal(new.frame, new.frame2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: but `complete.cases` won't do what you want if you have `NA` values in columns other than the focal (`z`) column and you want to retain rows that have `NA`s but not in the focal column ...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **na.omit** function on the whole dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 new.frame.nonull <- data[(!is.null(data$z)),]
 new.frame <- new.frame.nonull[(!is.na(new.frame.nonull$z)),]
```